# Grails - New log for each day

Tags: grails, log4j

I am trying to make logs in my grails app appear each day.  I have looked into this and can not get it to make a new log file each day and also include the date stamp in the log's name.  I'm sure this is a fairly simple thing to do, I just not having much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into Log4j's `DailyRollingFileAppender`. A couple of Grails examples:

- http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/grails-goodness-add-dailyrollingfileapp.html
- http://bradleybeddoes.com/2011/07/a-grails-logging-trick/